# How to match 2 unknown letters after a letter in php

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

i am trying to get this

```
string = 'Boss S02E06        more string'
```

i want `S02E06` out of the complete string . and if possible split the string there.
Please note that the values after S and E in that keep changing so its not constant .
But im not expert when it comes to it.But i guess its time to start learning.

Thanks guys

Comment: And [what have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)?

Comment: well ive done str_split but it only works for known string.....i done some examples to get 6 characters after S but that still dosent cut it

Comment: "unknown"? I guess you want match numbers/digits

Comment: well, you added preg-match, have you checked the documentation?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath yes, I'd imageine it's always `S[0-9]{2}E[0-9]{2}`. It's useful to get names of series' episodes, like "Boss Season 02 Episode 06" from the OP's example ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
$string = "Boss S02E06        more string";
preg_match(`.*(S\d+E\d+).*`,$string,$match);
echo $match[0];// it will echo S02E06
```

Comment: preg_match('.(S\d+E\d+).',$string,$match); worked                                without the '*'

Answer (score 0):

You would use a *Regular Expression*. You can learn them [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/).

PHP has `preg_match()`, which is what you would use.

The regex to match would be something like `S\d+E\d+`. If you want the values, use a capturing group.

It's up to you to put all these ideas together to arrive at an answer.